# Android background image not shown in device?

Tags: android, image, listview, background

I add the following code to `main.xml` to set an image as a background image for my app:

```
android:background="@drawable/bg"
```

So `main.xml` looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout 
xmlns:android= "http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:gravity="bottom|fill_vertical"
android:background="@drawable/bg0"
>
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/edWord"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="53px"
    android:textSize="20px"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:hint="" 
/>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android=
    "http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:scrollbars="vertical"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    >
    <ListView android:id="@+id/lstWord"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
    />

</LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
>
    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/btnGetText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:src="@drawable/get"
        android:layout_weight="0.25"
    />
    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/btnFind"
        android:text="Click me..."
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:src="@drawable/find"
        android:layout_weight="0.25"
    /> 

</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

And of course the image `bg.png` is in `drawable`.

The problem is that the background image is shown only in the emulator but not in my actual device (HTC Desire).

**What have I done wrong? What do I need to do to solve this problem?**

Can you guys there help? Thank you very much.

Comment: can you post the full xml file ?

Comment: Thank you very much, especially @NagarjunaReddy. In the end, I fix the problem myself as follows: `<ListView android:id="@+id/lstWord"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/bg0" 
    />
    ... `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem . Just remove `fill_parent` from the main Linear Layout Gravity. No need to set background in the Listview as you do right now. Just Change as i suggest it solve your problem.

```
android:gravity="bottom|fill_vertical"
```

Answer (score 1):

try this in place of that

```
<LinearLayout 
    xmlns:android= "http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/linearlayout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"            
        android:background="@drawable/bg" />
 </Linearlayout>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot but it removes all other images previously set in `main.xml`. I have edited my code in my post to reflect the whole scenario. Can you still help?

Comment: @edit your total xml file? it is use full to give corect answer.

Answer (score 0):

I got a similar bug my background drawable was shown in the graphical editor of eclipse but not on the devices I used for debugging.

-> For me it helped to clean the image (I just opened it in paint and saved it) after that i 
   overwrote the old image with the new one and copied it into the drawable folders.

Answer (score 0):

Some lolipop devices wouldn't show with higher resolution images. You could also manually resize the bitmap programmatically if you generate the backgrounds randomly or use a set of images to load them into the background